# Div disappear on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've run into a new problem...

I want the 'overlay' div to appear when the site is loaded, and when pressed, it goes away and shows the 'pause' div. And when the 'pause' div is then pressed, I need the 'overlay' div to come back. The script current looks as follows;

Script:

```
    $(function() {
  $(document).on("click",function (e) {
    if (e.target.id=="pause") {
      $("#overlay").fadeToggle(500);
      e.stopPropagation();
      return true;
    }
    else if ($("#overlay").is(":visible")) {
      $("#pause").fadeOut(500);
    }

    else if ($("#pause").is(":visible")) {
      $("#overlay").fadeOut(500);
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
        <div class="play">
            <img src="play.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" onclick="playMusic();">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pause">
        <img src="pause.png" style="height: 100%;">
    </div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/owr0sv8m/

Help would be wonderful, since I'm still a rookie at scripts...

Thanks in advance!
/ Chris

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` and `return true` seem to be at odds with one another

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the HTML code. It would be even more helpful if you posted this in jsfiddle.

Comment: SpoonMeiser, tried, but still not working...

David, updated HTML and JSFiddle coming in a minute!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to do something like this

```js
var overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");

function toggleClass() {
  this.classList.toggle("active")
}

overlay.addEventListener("click", toggleClass, false);
```

```css
#overlay .pause{
  display: none
}
#overlay.active .play{
  display: none
}
#overlay.active .pause {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class=active>
  <div class="play">
    <img src="play.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" onclick="playMusic();">
    <caption>Play</caption>
  </div>
  <div class="pause">
    <img src="pause.png" style="height: 100%;">
    <caption>Pause</caption>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if not try This

```js
var overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay"),
  pause = document.querySelector("#pause");

function toggleClassOnPause() {
  pause.classList.contains("active") ? pause.classList.remove("active") : overlay.classList.add("active");
  overlay.classList.add("active")
}

function toggleClassOnOverlay() {
  overlay.classList.contains("active") ? overlay.classList.remove("active") : overlay.classList.add("active");
  pause.classList.add("active")
}

pause.addEventListener("click", toggleClassOnPause, false);
overlay.addEventListener("click", toggleClassOnOverlay, false);
```

```css
#pause,
#overlay {
  display: none
}
#pause.active,
#overlay.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class=active>
  <div class="play">
    <img src="play.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" onclick="playMusic();">
    <caption>Overlay</caption>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pause">
  <img src="pause.png" style="height: 100%;">
  <caption>Pause</caption>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle and adopt it according to your need.
Pretty short and sweet.

html:

```
<div id="overlay" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #f0f0f0">
<div style="display: table;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <a style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
<div style="display: table;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <a style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="pause" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #f0f0f0">
<div style="display: table;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: gray">
    <a style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
<div style="display: table;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: gray">
    <a style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.visibleb {
  display:block !important;
}
#overlay,#pause {
  display:none;
}
```

javascript:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#overlay').addClass('visibleb');

       $(document).on("click",function (e) {
       $('#pause').toggleClass('visibleb');
       $('#overlay').toggleClass('visibleb');
              e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kodedsoft/bm4hhfsd/2/